# Expected expression ATM

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I was following along with a youtube video to a ATM using python and I got expected expression. I dont know how to fix it. line 32, 37 and 40.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlBfq.png)

Comment: A few things if your post gets closed - it's almost unanswerable right now so here's some things to do to make it better and get some help. First - post code into the question, don't post a screenshot of code. Second, we could use  more information - what does "ATM" mean in this context? What are you expecting and what are you getting instead? In short, please read the How to Ask guidelines and you should be able to fix up a good question.

Comment: I was trying to code to make a simple ATM (Automatic Teller Machine) through python.

Comment: Well that's part of it, but please also make the edits I suggested, otherwise as is it's a poorly-written question

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `elif` after an `else`. This is because `else` will capture all the remaining cases. Indentation, meaning spaces or tabs before the line is very important in Python.

Here is what I think you meant to write:

```py
balance = 1000
print("""
Welcome to Dutch Bank
Choose Transaction
1) BALANCE
2) WITHDRAW
3) DEPOSIT
4) EXIT
""")

while True:
    option = int(input("Enter Transaction"))
    if option == 1:
        print ("Your Balance is", balance)
        anothertrans = input("Do You Want to make another Transaction? Yes/No: ")
        if anothertrans == "YES":
            continue
        else:
            break
    elif option == 2:
        withdraw = float(input("Enter Amount To Withdraw"))

        if (balance > withdraw):
            total = balance - withdraw
            print("Success")
            print("Your New Balance is: ",total)
        else:
            print("Insufficient Balance")

    elif option == 3:
        deposit = float(input("Enter Amount To Deposit"))
        totalbalance = balance + deposit
        print("Sucess")
        print("Total Balance Now is: ", totalbalance)

    elif option == 4:
        print("Thank You ForBanking With Dutch Bank")
        exit()
    else:
        print ("No selected Transaction")
```

Comment: Still getting that expected error, on the elif option 3